# Splitting string in parts starting from back

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following issue:

If I have a given string `'abcdefg'` I want to split it in an array of substrings with length of 3 i.e. `[ 'abc', 'def']`

For that I use the String.prototype.match():

```
'abcdefg'.match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

However, if I have an input string with length which is not divisible by 3 `'abcdefgh'` the result is `['abc', 'def', 'gh']`, but I need the result to be `['ab', 'cde', 'fgh']`.

Is there an elegant way for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take a positive lookahead for following groups of three characters.

```js
console.log('abcdefgh'.match(/.{1,3}(?=(.{3})*$)/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first `reverse()` the string and then use `match()` and then `reverse()` back each part using `map()`

```js
const parts = str => [...str].reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g).map(x => [...x].reverse().join('')).reverse();

console.log(parts('abcdefgh'))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a for loop:

```
  const result = [];

  for(let i = str.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 3)
     result.unshift(str.slice(Math.max(0, i - 3), i));
```